# Add code to linux kernel that will create an I/O proc_entry and later, read the default value in this entry

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scheduler, readfile, proc

I have an assignment, where I have to create a proc_entry which can be written to(by user) and read from(by kernel).

The motive is that the kernel code should be able to read the value in the proc_entry, and use it later as a threshold for number  of files opened by a process. If a process has opened more files that this threshold, it will be penalized in the scheduler. As user can also change value inside this proc_entry, thus, kernel will use this threshold dynamically.

**Most of the codes I have seen online, tell how to create a *module* that will create such an entry, and another module that given the path of this entry, will read the string present.**

The code for the module to create I/O proc_entry is- (**Using the below module, I am able to create a proc_entry "/proc/my_proc_entry_write", to which, I can write using- "echo 200 > /proc/my_proc_entry_write", and read this value via "cat /proc/my_proc_entry_write"**)-

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
     #define DATA_SIZE 3000000 // We can keep 1024 bytes of data with us.
    #define MY_PROC_ENTRY "my_proc_entry_write"
    #define PROC_FULL_PATH "/proc/my_proc_entry_write"
    
    struct proc_dir_entry *proc;
    int len;
    char *msg = NULL;
    
    /*
     * Function to write to the proc. Here we free get the new value from buffer,
     * count from the buffer and then overwrite the data in our file.
     *
     * Note that - you can have any other implementation as well for this, all you have to
     * ensure that you comply with the expectations of the write() system calls
     * like filling in the buffer, and returning the numbers of character written.
     */
    
    static ssize_t my_proc_write(struct file *filp, const char __user * buffer, size_t count, loff_t *pos)  // buffer, of length count, should be copied to kernel
    {
        int i;
        char *data = PDE_DATA(file_inode(filp));   // gives data pointer of file
    
        if (count > DATA_SIZE) {
            return -EFAULT;
        }
    
        printk(KERN_INFO "Printing the data passed. Count is %lu", (size_t) count);
        for (i=0; i < count; i++) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Index: %d . Character: %c Ascii: %d", i, buffer[i], buffer[i]);    
        }
    
        printk(KERN_INFO "Writing to proc");
        if (copy_from_user(data, buffer, count)) {
            return -EFAULT;
        }
    
        data[count-1] = '\0';
    
        printk(KERN_INFO "msg has been set to %s", msg);   // Due to kmalloc, msg points to this. So, when we write, msg is changed.
        printk(KERN_INFO "Message is: ");
        for (i=0; i < count; i++) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "\n Index: %d . Character: %c", i, msg[i]);
        }
    
        *pos = (int) count;   // length written to be copied to pos at end
        len = count-1;       // len is length of string. count is len+1, to accomodate the \0.
    
        return count;
    }
    
    /*
     * Function to read the proc entry, here we copy the data from our proc entry 
     * to the buffer passed.
     */
    
    ssize_t my_proc_read(struct file *filp,char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp )   // copy to buf,which is in userspace
    {
        char* f_path; int i=0; char f_arr[128]; char* f_path_2;
    
        while(i<128)
        {
            f_arr[i]=0;
            i++;
        }
    
        f_path=dentry_path_raw(filp->f_path.dentry,f_arr,128);
       
        printk(KERN_ERR"f_path: %s\n",f_path);
    
        i=0;
        while(i<128 && f_arr[i]==0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(i!=128)
        {
            f_path_2=&f_arr[i];
            printk(KERN_ERR"f_path_2: %s\n",f_path_2);
        }
        
        int err;
        char *data = PDE_DATA(file_inode(filp));
    
        if ((int) (*offp) > len) {
            return 0;
        }
    
        printk(KERN_INFO "Reading the proc entry, len of the file is %d", len);
        if(!(data)) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "NULL DATA");
            return 0;
        }
    
        if (count == 0) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Read of size zero, doing nothing.");
            return count;
        } else {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Read of size %d", (int) count);
        }
    
        count = len + 1; // +1 to read the \0   ;  thus we store the previous written length in global variable len
        err = copy_to_user(buf, data, count); // +1 for \0
        printk(KERN_INFO "Read data : %s", buf);
        *offp = count;
    
        if (err) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Error in copying data.");
        } else {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Successfully copied data.");
        }
    
        return count;
    }
    
    
    /*
     * The file_operations structure. This is the glue layer which associates the
     * proc entry to the read and write operations.
     */
    struct file_operations proc_fops = {
        .read = my_proc_read,
        .write = my_proc_write,
    };
    
    
    /*
     * This function will create the proc entry. This function will allocate some
     * data where the data will be written incase of a write to the proc entry. The
     * same memory will be used to serve the reads.  * Initially the function fills
     * the data with DATA which has "100".
    
     * The important function to see here is the proc_create_data, this function
     * will take the proc entry name and create it with the given permissions
     * (0666). We also need to pass the file_operations structure which has the
     * function pointers to the functions which needs to be called when read or
     * write is called on the file. 
        The last argument has the pointer to the data
     * associated with the file. (So, by "char *data = PDE_DATA(file_inode(filp));", the 'data' is actually 'msg')
     */
    
    int create_new_proc_entry(void) {
        int i;
        char *DATA = "100";
        len = strlen(DATA);
        msg = kmalloc((size_t) DATA_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL); // +1 for \0
    
        if (msg != NULL) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Allocated memory for msg");
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    
        strncpy(msg, DATA, len+1);
        for (i=0; i < len +1 ; i++) {
            printk(KERN_INFO "%c", msg[i]);
            if (msg[i] == '\0') {
                printk(KERN_INFO "YES");
            }
        }
        proc = proc_create_data(MY_PROC_ENTRY, 0666, NULL, &proc_fops, msg);
        if (proc) {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    
    /* The init function of the module. Does nothing other than calling the
     * create_new_proc_entry. */
    
    int proc_init (void) {
        if (create_new_proc_entry()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    /* Function to remove the proc entry.  Call this when the module unloads. */
    void proc_cleanup(void) {
        remove_proc_entry(MY_PROC_ENTRY, NULL);
    }

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(proc_init);
module_exit(proc_cleanup);
```

Makefile for the above module is(**assuming the code of module is written in file proc_write_read.c**):-

```
MYPROC=proc_write_read
obj-m += $(MYPROC).o

export KROOT=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
#export KROOT=/lib/modules/$(uname)3.2.0-23-generic/build

allofit: modules

modules: clean
    @$(MAKE) -C $(KROOT) M=$(PWD) modules

modules_install:
    @$(MAKE) -C $(KROOT) M=$(PWD) modules_install

kernel_clean:
    @$(MAKE) -C $(KROOT) M=$(PWD) clean

clean: kernel_clean
    rm -rf   Module.symvers modules.order

insert: modules
    dmesg -c
    insmod proc_write_read.ko

remove: clean
    rmmod proc_write_read
```

**The module that reads this proc_entry, like a file is**-

```
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/syscalls.h>
    #include <linux/fcntl.h>
    #include <asm/uaccess.h>
    #include <linux/slab.h>
    #include <linux/string.h>
    
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/proc_fs.h>
    #include <linux/sched.h>
    #include <linux/mm.h>
    #include <linux/uaccess.h>
    #include <asm/types.h>
    
    int proc_init(void)
    {
    struct file *f; ssize_t ret = -EBADF;int i;
    char* f_path; 
    i=0;

    f=NULL;
    char buf[128]; char f_arr[128];
    mm_segment_t fs;
    
    i=0;

    while(i<128)
    {
        buf[i] = 0; 
        f_arr[i]=0;
        i++;
    }

    // To see in /var/log/messages that the module is operating
    //printk(KERN_INFO "read_file- my module is loaded\n");

    f = filp_open("/proc/my_proc_entry_write", O_RDONLY, 0);

    if (IS_ERR(f)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Error in filp_open: %p ; %d\n", f,PTR_ERR(f));
        return 100000;
    }

    f_path=dentry_path_raw(f->f_path.dentry,f_arr,128);
    printk(KERN_ERR"f_path_in_proc_entry_read: %s\n",f_path);

    printk(KERN_ERR"kernel Below1!!!\n");
    // Get current segment descriptor
    fs = get_fs();
    printk(KERN_ERR"kernel Below2!!!\n");
    // Set segment descriptor associated to kernel space
    set_fs(get_ds());
    printk(KERN_ERR"kernel Below3!!!\n");
    // Read the file
    if (f!=NULL) {
                if ((f->f_op)!=NULL && (f->f_op->read)!=NULL){
                    ret=f->f_op->read(f, buf, 128, &f->f_pos);
                    printk(KERN_ERR"kernel Below4!!!\n");
                }
                else
                   return 100000;
            
        }
        else
            return 100000;

    // Restore segment descriptor
    set_fs(fs);
    // See what we read from file
    printk(KERN_ERR "kernel Read my_proc_entry_write buf:%s\n",buf);

    int val=0;
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &val);

    printk(KERN_ERR"kernel val: %d\n",val);
   
    filp_close(f,NULL);

    return val;

    }
    
    void proc_cleanup(void)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "My module is unloaded\n");
    }
    
    
    module_init(proc_init);
    module_exit(proc_cleanup);
```

Makefile for the above module(**name=read_file_in_kernel**) is-

```
obj-m += read_file_in_kernel.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

My question is- **Both these modules work fine as userspace modules, via insmod**, but if I copy-paste this code to  the source code of **kernel 4.19.200** (not exact copy-paste, just the main parts as functions), and use the 2nd module,i.e, read_file_in_kernel's code to access the proc value, I am getting an error, i.e, kernel is not able to boot.
On running gdb through the kernel, I found that the code in read_file_in_kernel went through the below code, thrice (i.e, when update_curr function in linux kernel called this function 3 times),i.e, **f is being returned as an error every time**-

```
if (IS_ERR(f)) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "Error in filp_open: %p ; %d\n", f,PTR_ERR(f));
    return 100000;
}
```

In the 4th call to read_file_in_kernel, **the kernel froze on** -

```
f = filp_open("/proc/my_proc_entry_write", O_RDONLY, 0);
```

Same case with gdb.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Is it that /proc/my_proc_entry_write is not being created during bootup when it is read, and so, **filp_open** is not able to open that proc_entry to be read.
I even tried removing the first module from kernel entirely, **running it separately from user-space to create a proc_entry(my_proc_entry_write) beforehand, that will be loaded by default every time the kernel boots up**. But still, same error is coming.

What correction should I make to this?
If this is not the way to create a dynamic proc_entry that can be written to by user and ready by kernel, what is?

Comment: In general, it is not good practice to do user-space file access from kernel code. If you need to access the buffer contents from another module, either export a variable pointing to the buffer directly, or export a function to copy data from the buffer. That is what the `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` and `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL()` macros are for.

Comment: Hi @IanAbbott . The motive is that kernel should read what user writes, so that some dynamic behaviour exists.     I need to be able to read the value in the buffer in update_curr() method, which is part of the main kernel code. As EXPORT_SYMBOL() allows reading of variables from one module to another, this won't run there(I tried accessing such a variable in main kernel code and it gave compile-time error).

Comment: /proc will be mounted from user space, so it will not be mounted until sometime after the kernel has created the `init` process.

Comment: @IanAbbott , I modified the update_curr() method a bit, such that the 'read_file_in_kernel()' method(which reads the buffer/proc value) will be called from update_curr(), after some time of the kernel booting.   When read_file_in_kernel hasn't been called yet, my kernel boots up, and I can see my proc entry created to which I can read and write.  But after that time, when update_curr calls read_file_in_kernel, it gave error, and the kernel froze.  So, /proc has been mounted, but still, filp_open() froze when reading this proc entry.

Comment: Well you probably shouldn't be trying to do complicated stuff like reading files in the middle of the scheduling code.